# jquery wordpress Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Sup , guys I have a problem with jquery functions.I want to remake todo list plugin 
for wordpress and I have this error when I am trying to add some text to todo list.
*"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined"*

What should i do to fix this? Could u help me please?

Here is the code:

```js
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var url  = WP_API_Settings.root + 'wp/v2/todos/';
    var form = $( '.form' );
    var list = $( '.list' );

    function template( data ) {
        var html = '';

        html += '<li class="list-item' + ( data.acf.done ? ' list-item-checked' : '' ) + '" data-id="' + data.id + '">';
            html += '<label class="list-item-label">';
                html += '<input type="checkbox" class="list-check" value="1" name="field[done]" ' + ( data.acf.done ? 'checked' : '' )+ '>';
                html += '<p class="list-title">' + data.title.rendered + '</p>';
                html += '<a href="#" class="btn btn-remove">remove</a>';
            html += '</label>';
        html += '</li>';

        return html;
    }

    // Load todos
    $.get( url + '?orderby=id&order=asc&per_page=100', function( data ){
        for( var i in data ) {
            list.prepend( template( data[i] ) );
        }
    }, 'json' );

    // Save todo
    form.submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = $( this );       
        var data = self.serialize();

        $.ajax( {
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                // https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', WP_API_Settings.nonce );
            },
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json'
        } )
        .done( function ( data ) {
            list.prepend( template( data ) );
            self.find( '.input-text' ).val( '' );
        } )
        .fail( function( data ) {
            alert( data.responseJSON.message );
        } );
    } );

    // Change state of todo
    list.on( 'change', '.list-check', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = $( this );
        var item = self.closest( '.list-item' );
        var id = item.data( 'id' );
        var data = {
            'fields[done]': self.is( ':checked' ) ? 1 : 0
        };

        $.ajax( {
            url: url + id,
            method: 'PUT',
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                // https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', WP_API_Settings.nonce );
            },
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json'
        } )
        .done( function ( data ) {
            if ( data.acf.done ) {
                item.addClass( 'list-item-checked' );
            } else {
                item.removeClass( 'list-item-checked' );
            }
        } )
        .fail( function( data ) {
            alert( data.responseJSON.message );
        } );;
    } );

    // Remove todo
    list.on( 'click', '.btn-remove', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = $( this );
        var item = self.closest( '.list-item' );
        var id = item.data( 'id' );

        $.ajax( {
            url: url + id,
            method: 'DELETE',
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                // https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', WP_API_Settings.nonce );
            }
        } )
        .done( function( data ) {
            item.fadeOut( 'fast', function() {
                $( this ).remove();
            } );
        } )
        .fail( function( data ) {
            alert( data.responseJSON.message );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(data.responseJSON)`?

Comment: I have tried to replace alert(data.responseJson.message) on console.log and I get undefined after adding todo ( here is demo :http://airesgoncalves.com.br/to-do-list/  in demo it works but i don't know why i have this error in my case )

Comment: Just `data.responseJson`, what's the value of that?

Comment: value is undefined

Comment: Then check for `data` value

Comment: I have checked only data value and I get "[object Object]"